# Prove the converse of convolution theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

I am trying to prove the converse of convolution theorem:
$$ \mathscr{F}[f(x)g(x)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\widetilde{f}(\omega)*\widetilde{g}(\omega)$$

I try to apply the definition of convolution and Fourier tranform:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\widetilde{f}(\omega)*\widetilde{g}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\widetilde{f}(\omega)\widetilde{g}(z-\omega)\,d\omega \\ 
&= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^3\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}\,dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)e^{-i(z-\omega) y}\,dy\right]\,d\omega
\end{align*}
obviously my aim is to obtain $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)e^{-i\omega x}\,dx$, but I don't have any idea on how to proceed. Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you.

---

I found the solution here: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html

Comment: Why do you not use Fourier inversion?

Comment: I still don't get it. Would you please elaborate it?

Comment: Apply $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ to both sides.

Comment: Do you mean start from $1/\sqrt{2\pi}\mathcal F^{-1}[\widetilde{f}(\omega)*\widetilde{g}(\omega)]$ and try to obtain $f(x)g(x)$? I obtained $1/\sqrt{2\pi}\mathcal F^{-1}[\widetilde{f}(\omega)*\widetilde{g}(\omega)]=-1/(2\pi)\int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\widetilde{f}(\omega)\widetilde{g}(\omega)e^{i\omega(x-z)}\,d\omega\,dx$, and can't proceed.